# Java and Batch doesn't want to load main class

Tags: java, batch-file

```
@echo off
title Windows
color a

set mainclass="Interface"

:start
if exist "%HOMEDRIVE%/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/"  goto x64(J7)
if exist "%HOMEDRIVE%/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/" goto x86(J7)

if exist "%HOMEDRIVE%/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/"  goto x64(J6)
if exist "%HOMEDRIVE%/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/" goto x86(J6)
if defined java goto :x121

:x121
CLS
java -Xmx1024m %mainclass%
pause
exit

:x64(J6)
CLS
"%HOMEDRIVE%/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/java.exe" -Xmx1024m %mainclass%
pause
exit


:x86(J6)
CLS
"%HOMEDRIVE%/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/java.exe" -Xmx1024m %mainclass%
pause
exit

:x64(J7)
CLS
"%HOMEDRIVE%/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe" -Xmx1024m %mainclass%
pause
exit

:x86(J7)
CLS
"%HOMEDRIVE%/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/java.exe" -Xmx1024m %mainclass%
pause
exit
```

This problem has been occurring with ONLY this program. Every time I try to load my java program via this batch script, which has worked every since its inception, it gives me a "could not find or load main class" error. Some one please inform me what I'm doing wrong since I just tested this code out with a different java file not 5 minutes ago and it worked.

Comment: You are not specifying any classpath on the commandline. You essentially run `java.exe -Xmx1024m Interface`

Comment: When you say this Java file, do you mean you have another Java program which incorporates a batch job working?  Or you just have another Java class that works via script?

Comment: @MohammadS. This batch file is a loader, which I use for my java programs that require a terminal. It only executes the class file and gives me the terminal I need.

Comment: Never mind, I found out what was wrong. I exported the java file incorrectly out of the IDE. :/

Comment: @Arc If you solved your problem, it would be helpful if you could create your own answer to the question and then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem by taking off the 'package InterfacePackage;' at the top of the java file. I recompiled then it worked fine.